# Python Stop Splinter from Waiting for Everything to Load

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

Right now Splinter will load for 20 seconds on pages with lots of ads and tracking built in

```
browser.visit("https://www.website.com")
```

I know that selenium allows for

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"
```

But Splinter doesn't accept these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the capabilities when initiate the browser

```
browser = Browser('firefox', capabilities={'pageLoadStrategy': True})
browser.visit("https://www.website.com")
```

Comment: Ah, they go in capabilities={}! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

True answer is set `pageLoadStrategy` to `normal`:

```
browser = Browser('firefox', capabilities={'pageLoadStrategy': 'normal'})
browser.visit('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```